# Different Security for different Service operation in WCF

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I am designing and testing WCF Services and exposing them as SOAP Web Services.

I have my service classes divided logically.  I have an Account service.  To access the account web service you have to provide a user name and password and an API token.  I wrote a custom class extending UserNamePasswordValidator to taje care of the authentication and an IDispatchMessageInspector to check for the token.

A requirement has just surfaced where we want to provide some account checking without the user being authenticated.  Logically these operation should remain in the Account Service.  However the service Behavior is configured to require username, password and has an IServiceBehavior which adds an IDispatchMessageInspector the checks all massages for a token.

I have been reviewing all of the different extension points via [Extending Dispatchers - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and  [WCF Extensibility - Carlos Figueira](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/)

I can seem to find a way to only apply security at the operation level.  Or a way to configure the service so certain functions require security/token and other do not.

I'm new to WCF so it could be something simple but I haven't found it.   If you know of an article showing how to secure different parts of a service in different ways or if you know how, please provide me with some info.  Thank you.

Comment: For this you can create separate endpoint ('free'/public service) without security or with different security settings

Comment: How can I limit the operations in that endpoint?  If there is no authentication, I want to limit what can be called.

Comment: You expose endpoint with special interface, different from main (only restricted operations)

Comment: I will look into this.  I was hoping to use something more configuration based,  I would prefer not to have to write special interfaces every time security requirements change.

Comment: If you talking about some declarative security with method attributes (for example) - it is not better (you need to add attribute and recompile). Having one 'free' service interface - it is convenient.

Comment: Even configurable security (XML).  I don't mind recompiling - I would like to just take a service and say - this function is an operation that needs a password, this one does not - currently I add a message interceptor to check for tokens and a custom user validator, but these both occur at the Service level.  I would like to see it at the operation level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to allow/deny permission at operation level, you can set your methods with **PrincipalPermission** attribute.

You can use like this:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Authenticated=false)]
void NotAutenticationRequiredMethod()
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Authenticated=true)]
void AuthenticationRequiredMethod()
```

As you want something more “flexible”, you can also use roles, so no recompile will be needed:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CustomRole")]
```

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649821.aspx

At method level you can also check you the **OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext** object to verify if the request if from a authenticated user and make some decision.

Remember that **SecurityContext** can have different authentications:

```
string primaryIdentity = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;

string windowsIdentity = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
```

Read more here: https://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/identity-securitycallcontext-in-wcf/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  The roles solve part of my problem.  What about the tokens?  2 different operations require different tokens to work.  Right now I am using a IMessageInspector but it checks all messages, how can imspect the message at the operation level?

Comment: The authentication data, including the token you access with OperationContext object. Are you passing the token in MessageHeader? If so, you can read the token at operation level in the header using OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.